# How do I automatically quit app when disconnecting the power cable on Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook, battery-life, macos-sierra

I have a Macbook Pro with macOS Sierra. I have the Suunto Moveslink2 application running in the background, but I really only need the app when I connect my sports watch to my mac (1-2 a day). According to macOS, it uses a lot of battery and I usually forget to quit the app when I disconnect my power cable. Is there any way to make my Mac automatically quit the app every time I unplug?

I do not need the app to start when I connect the power cable again, I can launch the app manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for my problem. An app called ControlPlane can actually do what I wanted, but it can also just launch the required app when I connect my sport watch, and quit the app as soon as I disconnect it. My setup right now:

- Download and install CrashPlane from its website https://www.controlplaneapp.com/
- A minimal working setup could be (each major bullet point corresponds to a pane in the ControlPlane preferences)
- Contexts

  - Create a context named `Ambit attached`
- Evidence sources

  - enable `Attached USB Device`. The other sources can be disabled to improve performance
- Rules

  - Click the plus sign and choose `Add ‘attached usb device’ rule`
  - If your ambit is connected, it should show up the in uppermost field. Choose context `Ambit attached` and set the confidence to maximum. Hit OK
- Actions

  - Add an `open file or application` action. Choose the Moveslink application (normally /Applications/Moveslink2.app), set the context `Ambit attached`. The other settings can be left as is (i.e ‘on arrival’, no delay and enabled)
  - Add a `quit application` action and give the parameter `Moveslink2.app`. Set the context to `Ambit attached` and choose `On departure`.

This working on macOS Sierra v10.12.3, running ControlPlane 1.6.5, the Moveslink2.app from Suunto and the Suunto Ambit3 sport watch.